# Linux Kernel with Docker on Windows doesn't match WSL Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, windows, azure, docker, linux-kernel

I'm trying to mount Azure Files with this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux) but I'm having trouble mounting. I'm using Docker Desktop to develop deployment containers and the tutorial says it requires Linux Kernel >=4.11. Despite WSL/Ubuntu having kernel 4.19, when I run my Docker containers, the kernel shows up as `4.9.184-linuxkit` when I run `uname -r`. I thought that Debian:buster used a newer kernel, so I'm not sure why my kernel is out of date in the containers. I updated to WSL2, but that didn't seem to help.

Edit: Found something about [Docker Desktop and WSL2](https://engineering.docker.com/2019/06/docker-hearts-wsl-2/), but I'm not sure what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the Docker container linux kernel to match Windows by doing the following:

1. Enroll in Windows Insider Program and choose the **Fast** channel
2. [Install/enable WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install)
3. Upgrade to the Edge channel in Docker Desktop for Windows
4. Enable WSL integration Docker Desktop -> Settings -> Resources -> WSL Integration
5. Verify with `docker run -it debain:buster /bin/bash` and `uname -r`