# Unable to run docker for windows

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to run docker commands on my local machine, I installed docker for windows but its getting error, not sure how to resolve this. How do I update this WSL kernel version.

[image]

Comment: (kill all docker processes,) Open (administrative) cmd/pwsh, enter: `wsl --update` (alternatively via "app store"/windows update.../follow link;)

Comment: I think this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59379598/16686308

Comment: @xerx593 C:\Windows\system32>wsl --update
Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux
The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

Comment: Assuming you met ["prerequisites" and followed installation manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).. you can only try to "re-enable"/"identify interfering processes"/re-install/search for [similar issues/solutions](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7746)